# cmake "Cannot find MySQL" (using XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, cmake, mysql-connector, mysql-connect

I'm using XAMPP to install and run MySQL, and when I run `me@host:/path/to/mysql-connector-cpp> cmake .`, it throws

```
-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/include
-- ENV{MYSQL_DIR} = 
CMake Error at FindMySQL.cm:202 (MESSAGE):
  mysql_config wasn't found, -DMYSQL_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:166 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at FindMySQL.cm:204 (MESSAGE):
  Cannot find MySQL.  Include dir: MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND library dir:
  cxxflags:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:166 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm using XAMPP so I'm sure cmake is looking for MySQL in the wrong directory. How do I tell it where it's located?

Answer (score 0):

You could point it to proper `mysql-config` executable:

```
cmake -D MYSQL_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/mysql-config .
```

Or you can just define needed vars:

```
cmake -D MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR=... -D MYSQL_LIBRARY_DIR .
```

Comment: In my case under Windows I had to use this command line: cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=d:\Listati\Siti\boost_1_55_0 -DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR:STRING=d:\xampp\mysql\include -DMYSQL_LIB_DIR:STRING=d:\xampp\mysql\lib